# How to show only categories in homepage in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, categories

I want to display all categories with an image in wordpress homepage. I dont want to display posts in homepage. When visitors will click on that image , then he will go to that category posts. How can i do it ? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by installing the [Category Images](https://wordpress.org/plugins/categories-images) plugin, adding images to the categories. Next add the following code to the index.php page:

```
<ul>
 <?php foreach (get_categories() as $cat) : ?>
 <li>
 <a href="<?php echo get_category_link($cat->term_id); ?>">
<?php echo $cat->cat_name; ?>
<br>
<img src="<?php echo z_taxonomy_image_url($cat->term_id); ?>" /></a>
 </li>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

The above code will display the category name and image for each category that have a post assigned to it. Clicking on the category name or image will bring you to the category posts.

Comment: Thanks for help. But in homepage the posts are also coming. I want only categories to appear with images. Please help. Please suggest me a theme where i can have that facility.

Comment: @AmitPal, what is the code in the index.php file? If there is  `<?php /* Start the Loop */ ?><?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?> <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?><?php endwhile; ?>
<?php twentytwelve_content_nav( 'nav-below' ); ?>` you will need to remove it